# Highcharts drilldown async multi serie issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

We are founding an issue on doing highchart drilldown when we have more than one serie of data.

When someone clicks on any column, highchart remove just one of the main series. Then, when the "Back To" button is clicked, chart data becomes completely confused.

Below, the code:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                    if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                        var chart = this,
                            drilldowns = {
                                'Animals': {
                                    name: 'Animals',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Cows', 2],
                                        ['Sheep', 3]
                                    ]
                                },
                                'Fruits': {
                                    name: 'Fruits',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Apples', 5],
                                        ['Oranges', 7],
                                        ['Bananas', 2]
                                    ]
                                },
                                'Cars': {
                                    name: 'Cars',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Toyota', 1],
                                        ['Volkswagen', 2],
                                        ['Opel', 5]
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            series = drilldowns[e.point.name];
                        chart.showLoading('Simulating Ajax ...');

                            chart.hideLoading();
                            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);

                    }

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Async drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Things',  
            data: [{
                name : 'Animals',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: true
            }, {
            name : 'Fruits',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: true
            }, {
                name : 'Cars',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: true
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Dois',  
            data: [{
                name : 'Animals',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: true
            }, {
                name : 'Fruits',
                y: 9,
                drilldown: true
            }, {
                name : 'Cars',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: true
            }]
        }],

        drilldown: {
            series: []
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Just tested on jsFiddle, works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3T8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you notice that you have unpaired parenthesis? The second last line is redundant.